# Where I use useMemo and useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying understand `useMemo` and `useCallback`. I watch videos but I understand?
What are this hooks and where I use?

Comment: Official documentation is a great resource, probably better than random videos: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo They are used in functional React components following the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Is there a more specific or particular aspect you are trying to understand?

Comment: You use them to memoize (cache) something. They do nothing more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For beginners, I suggest you use [`why-did-you-render`](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render). Learning when should and should not use them is kind of vague.